# Cucumber step definitions not linked

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I upgraded my serenity and cucumber tests today to version 2.6.0 en cucumber 6. Only to have a lot of package needed to change and the steps of my feature files no longer linked to the step definitions. If if this setup for my cucumberrunner

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"be.nbb.hive.cucumber.steps"})
public class CucumberRunner {
}
```

But if I look in intellij in the feature files you can no longer click through the steps to go to the definition. And when I run a feature file I get following exception:

```
10:40:50.005 [main] DEBUG n.thucydides.core.steps.StepEventBus - Test suite started for story net.thucydides.core.model.Story@aa2c74aa
10:40:50.006 [main] INFO   - Test Suite Started: Smoke Test Login
sep 09, 2021 10:40:50 AM io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime run
SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 15
^I click on (?:?:the )?\?(?:.*)?(?:?:.*)? \((name|id|css|xpath\): \?(?:.+)?\\)$
               ^
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:93)
    at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.run(Main.java:27)
    at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 15
^I click on (?:?:the )?\?(?:.*)?(?:?:.*)? \((name|id|css|xpath\): \?(?:.+)?\\)$
               ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2123)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2821)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1054)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.DefaultPatternCompiler.compile(DefaultPatternCompiler.java:12)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.TreeRegexp.<init>(TreeRegexp.java:22)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpression.<init>(CucumberExpression.java:37)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.ExpressionFactory.createExpression(ExpressionFactory.java:34)
    at io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.StepExpressionFactory.crateExpression(StepExpressionFactory.java:88)
    at io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.StepExpressionFactory.createExpression(StepExpressionFactory.java:61)
    at io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.StepExpressionFactory.createExpression(StepExpressionFactory.java:49)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.lambda$prepareGlue$3(CachingGlue.java:244)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.prepareGlue(CachingGlue.java:243)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:70)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$5(Runtime.java:110)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:117)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$6(Runtime.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:86)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:204)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1351)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87)
    ... 2 more
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong as the same code worked with the previous version

Answer (score -1):

This is a question related to upgrading to Cucumber 6, which has a different API, syntax and and architecture compared to Cucumber 2. You will need to rewrite many of the step definition methods, as the regular expressions used in Cucumber 2 will need updating, and the parameter conversion logic will also need updating (different classes are used).